# Deleting all tags on an Azure resource/resgroup via REST

Tags: r, rest, azure, azure-resource-manager, httr

According to the Docs, I can update the tags on a [resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/update) or [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/update) by making a PATCH request and setting the `tags` field in the body. This works for setting one or more tags, or deleting one or more tags (I just leave the tagname out of the request).

However, when I try to delete *all* the tags by passing an empty `tags` field:

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/{....}

{
  "tags": {}
}
```

it doesn't work. For a resource, I get a 400 error `Request must specify an account property to update` while for a resource group, it just leaves the current tags unchanged.

Is there a way to delete all the tags on a resource/resource group via REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually [due to a wart](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/573) in how the httr package handles empty fields in a request body. If the body is a list, such fields are silently removed before being sent to the host.

The fix is to convert the data into JSON beforehand, rather than relying on httr to do it:

```
httr::PATCH("https://management.azure.com/{....}",
    body=jsonlite::toJSON(body, auto_unbox=TRUE),
    encoding="raw",
    ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use this api: [Resources - Update By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/updatebyid), it should apply to both the resource and resource group. I have test it with the resource group and a resource(my sample is a web app), all work fine.

The request body:

```
{
  tags: {}
}
```

**Note**: If you get a `NoRegisteredProviderFound` error, change the api-version depends on the error message.

Comment: It actually turned out to be due to a wart in the R httr package, which I was using to talk to Azure.

Comment: @HongOoi Not familiar with r, if my reply is helpful, you could accept it as the answer ;-)

Comment: why would he accept it if it is clearly not an answer?

Comment: @4c74356b41 In the original question, he did not mention he used r, to the original question, I think my reply is clear enough.

Comment: nobody except you knows about the original question at this point

Comment: @4c74356b41 Under the question, click `edited 15 mins ago` ,you can check it.

Comment: you realize nobody would do that

Comment: @JoyWang I've upvoted your answer; thanks for taking the effort to have a look.